# How to make Shiny give back memory after a session ends?

Tags: r, memory, shiny, ram

I have a shiny app that allows each user to select which data set to load.  Everything in the app works wonderful, except for memory usage.  After the session is ended and the user closes the web browser, Shiny does not give back the free memory to the machine it is running on.  Eventually, after accessing it enough times, it runs out of memory.

In traditional R, I often take care of this with frequent calls to gc() after removing data.  However, that does not seem to work in my shiny app.

Hours of googling has not rendered anything insightful.  Is there a clean way of freeing up unused memory in this scenario?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333858/how-to-clean-up-r-memory-without-the-need-to-restart-r-session/70841811#70841811) you can find a related answer and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3953) a related GitHub issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can `gc()` under `observe` statement with `invalidateLater`? Also maybe you can limit each session to some memory threshold or some timeout if possible? Below you can see how much memory you are taking for each session. Also look at your Task Manager in the Processes how much this process takes in (note: current example takes about `440Mb` per session)

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

cleanMem <- function(n=10) { for (i in 1:n) gc() }

runApp(list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tableOutput('foo')
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    
    observe({
      # periodically collect
      invalidateLater(1000,session)
      cleanMem()
    })

    x1 <- 1:100000000
    x2 <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars)
    env <- environment()  # can use globalenv(), parent.frame(), etc
    output$foo <- renderTable({
      data.frame(
        object = ls(env),
        size = unlist(lapply(ls(env), function(x) {
          object.size(get(x, envir = env, inherits = FALSE))
        }))
      )
    })
  }
))
```

Comment: This answer is useful and the example works exactly like I want my code to work by freeing up memory.  However, it does not free up the memory when I apply the example to my code.  I know now how it should work, it's on me to figure out why it's not working that way!!!  I'll see if I can post an example of my code here.