# How to clean up R memory without the need to restart R session

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection

I know there are plenty of similar questions with accepted answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670269/clear-memory-allocated-by-r-session-gc-doesnt-help), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579765/how-to-clean-up-r-memory-without-the-need-to-restart-my-pc#comment15322947_11579765) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813753/what-is-the-difference-between-gc-and-rm)), but so far nowhere I found a clear answer on how to free some memory space without restarting your R session.

I know, one could save his workspace, restart R and load back the workspace but:

1. I am not sure, but doing so you will have to load back all the libraries right?
2. If your workspace is huge, it may take time to do so, and if I do that quite often I don't want to loose time each time I do it.
3. If I delete a big object, isn't just a normal behavior to actually *release* the memory this object was occupying?

This doesn't seem to be the case. Even after removing half of the biggest objects of my workspace (thanks to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395270/determining-memory-usage-of-objects#1395280)) and after running `gc()`, `top` still gives me the exact same % of memory used.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579765/how-to-clean-up-r-memory-without-the-need-to-restart-my-pc#comment15322947_11579765) in a comment it says:

> R's garbage collection "marks" the RAM as available. Up to your OS to
>   reclaim that

Sounds ok but not sure this really happen. `top` still shows me the same amount of memory used by R even after `rm()` and `gc()`, and even after starting new other process in the os, and even after 2h, 10h or 3 days.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670269/clear-memory-allocated-by-r-session-gc-doesnt-help#comment41946843_26670269) comment suggest that it has to see with loaded libraries and graphic devices, but why? and how I can solve it?

If I `rm()` a `3GB` object and then use `gc()` to free the memory, how is it possible that R still use the same percentage of memory?

Comment: I still haven't any rational explenation for that. I saw the option `reset=TRUE` in `gc()`, sometime it helps to actually free the memory but sometime not. I realize that if I do `rm(object)` and  `gc()` right after the generation of the big object it works, but if I do other things in-between no, though I am not sure what are the _exact_ things that make the `rm()` useless

Comment: @LazarusThurston I can't reproduce this. On my machine, `x <- double(1e+09); rm(x); gc()` allocates ~8 GB of memory, then frees it, and that is reflected in the `top` output. Can you provide a a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Perhaps this is Ubuntu related : https://askubuntu.com/q/507699

Comment: gc() works only in straight back to back removals. In real life situations, when you create multiple vairables and then remove them in a different sequence, it doesnt work even if you wait 2 hours or 8 hours.. I have used Ubuntu 16 and 18 and both give the same trouble. And ultimately I have to restart R.

Comment: I had this problem with Debian, this was couple of years ago not sure I could do a reproducible example, but as @LazarusThurston said, it happens mostly for long sessions, with lot of variables, `rm()` calls and libraries loads. Never found a neat solution and just gave up with it. Now I try to clean big variables as soon and often as possible.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Garbage collection is "complicated". If `x` is a variable bound in an environment `e`, then `rm(x, pos = e); gc()` does not necessarily free `object.size(e$x)` bytes for use by the OS.

That is because R objects are just pointers to blocks of memory. If multiple objects point to the same block of memory, then you need to remove all of them to make that memory available for garbage collection. That can be hard to do if your global environment binds a large number of variables—possibly recursively, if you make frequent use of lists (including data frames), pairlists, and environments (including function evaluation environments).

Here is an example, which I've run on a machine with 8 GB RAM running Ubuntu 20.04. (It should be reproducible on most Unix-alikes, but not on Windows due to the Unix command in the `system` call.)

```bash
$ R --vanilla
```

```r
## Force garbage collection then output the amount of memory
## being used by R, as seen by R ('gc') and by the OS ('ps')
usage <- function() {
    m1 <- sum(gc(FALSE)[, "(Mb)"])
    m2 <- as.double(system(paste("ps -p", Sys.getpid(), "-o pmem="), intern = TRUE))
    c(`gc (MiB)` = m1, `ps (%)` = m2)
}
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     19.0     0.6

## Allocate a large block of memory and create multiple
## references to it
x <- double(1e+08)
y <- x
l <- list(x = x)
p <- pairlist(x = x)
e <- new.env(); e$x <- x
f <- (function(x) {force(x); function(x) x})(x)

usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    786.1    10.3

## Apply 'object.size' to each object in current environment 
## and scale from bytes to mebibytes
0x1p-20 * unlist(eapply(environment(), object.size))
##            x            y        usage            e            f            l            p 
## 7.629395e+02 7.629395e+02 1.787567e-02 5.340576e-05 1.106262e-03 7.629398e+02 7.629396e+02

## Remove references to double(1e+08) one by one
rm(x); usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    786.1    10.3 

rm(y); usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    786.1    10.3

l$x <- NULL; usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    786.1    10.3

p$x <- NULL; usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    786.1    10.3

rm(x, pos = e); usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    786.1    10.3

rm(x, pos = environment(f)); usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     23.2     0.6
```

This example shows that `object.size` is not a reliable means of determining what variables you need to remove in order to return a certain block of memory to the OS. To actually free the ~760 MiB (~800 MB) allocated for `double(1e+08)`, it was necessary to remove six references: `x`, `y`, `l$x`, `p$x`, `e$x`, and `environment(f)$x`.

Your observation that `gc` appears to do nothing only in long-running R processes with many variables bound in the global environment makes me suspect that you have removed some but not all references to the blocks of memory that you are trying to free. I wouldn't jump to the conclusion that the garbage collector is behaving incorrectly, especially without a minimal reproducible example.

#### That said...

Issues with memory deallocation on Linux *have* been discussed on the R-devel mailing list and on Bugzilla. It is even covered in the R FAQ. Here are the most relevant links:

1. *Why is R apparently not releasing memory?* [R FAQ 7.42](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-R-apparently-not-releasing-memory_003f)
2. *Help to create bugzilla account*, R-devel [[1]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-August/074763.html) ... very poorly titled
3. *Issue with memory deallocation/fragmentation on systems which use glibc*, R-devel [[2]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-June/074487.html), [[3]](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2017-July/074614.html)
4. *R doesn't release memory to the system*, [BR 14611](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14611)
5. *glibc malloc doesn't release memory to the system*, [BR 17505](https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17505)

To summarize, it turns out that there *is* an issue on Linux, but it is due to a limitation of glibc that is outside of R's control. Specifically, when glibc allocates then deallocates many small blocks of memory, you can end up with a [fragmented heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770457/what-is-memory-fragmentation) from which the OS is unable to reclaim unused memory.

#### Minimal reproducible example

We can reproduce the issue in R by creating a long list of short atomic vectors, rather than one very long atomic vector:

```bash
$ R --vanilla
```

```r
usage <- function() {
    m1 <- sum(gc(FALSE)[, "(Mb)"])
    m2 <- as.double(system(paste("ps -p", Sys.getpid(), "-o pmem="), intern = TRUE))
    c(`gc (MiB)` = m1, `ps (%)` = m2)
}
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     19.0     0.6

x <- replicate(1e+06, runif(100), simplify = FALSE)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    847.1    15.9

rm(x)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     23.2    15.8
```

Indeed, the OS is unable to reclaim most of the memory that was occupied by `x` and its elements. It continues to reserve ~15% of RAM for the R process, even though only ~23 MiB of that memory is used.

(That is on my Linux machine. On my Mac, which has twice as much RAM, the percentage memory used as reported by the OS changes from 0.4 to 6.2 to 1.2.)

#### Possible fixes

A few work-arounds were suggested in the mailing list threads:

1. Set environment variables to tune the behaviour of glibc. No advice or example was provided, so you'll have to do a deep dive to figure this out. You might start with the `mallopt` [man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html).
2. Instruct R to use an allocator other than glibc's `malloc`, such as `jemalloc` or `tcmalloc`. Luke Tierney wrote:

   > ... it is possible to use alternate `malloc` implementations, either rebuilding R to use them or using `LD_PRELOAD`. On Ubuntu for example, you can have R use `jemalloc` with
   >
   > ```
   > sudo apt-get install libjemalloc1
   > env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.1 R
   > ```
   >
   > This does not seem to hold onto memory to the same degree, but I don't know about any other aspect of its performance.
3. Explicitly call the glibc utility `malloc_trim` to instruct the OS to reclaim unused memory where possible. The `malloc_trim` [man-page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) says:

   > Since glibc 2.8 this function frees memory in all arenas and in all chunks with whole free pages.

   which seems promising!

Dmitry Selivanov compared `malloc`, `jemalloc`, `tcmalloc`, and `malloc`+`malloc_trim` [here](https://github.com/dselivanov/r-malloc). They showed convincingly that all of `jemalloc`, `tcmalloc`, and `malloc`+`malloc_trim` can help mitigate fragmentation issues seen with `malloc`. Some caveats:

- They only tested on Ubuntu 16.04.
- They didn't share what versions of glibc, libjemalloc1, and libtcmalloc-minimal4 they had installed.
- They showed that none of the `malloc` alternatives is a panacea. They rarely performed *worse* than `malloc`, but they did not always perform *better*.

#### Some experiments

I retried the above `replicate` example using each of the `malloc` alternatives in turn. In this (nongeneralizable) experiment, `jemalloc` and `tcmalloc` did not perform much better than `malloc`, while `malloc`+`malloc_trim` allowed the OS to reclaim all deallocated memory. Here are the libraries that I used:

```
libc6                 version 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
libjemalloc2          version 5.2.1-1ubuntu1
libtcmalloc-minimal4  version 2.7-1ubuntu2
```

See below for results.

##### `jemalloc`

```bash
$ sudo apt install libjemalloc2
$ env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2 R --vanilla
```

```r
usage <- function() {
    m1 <- sum(gc(FALSE)[, "(Mb)"])
    m2 <- as.double(system(paste("ps -p", Sys.getpid(), "-o pmem="), intern = TRUE))
    c(`gc (MiB)` = m1, `ps (%)` = m2)
}
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     19.0     0.6

x <- replicate(1e+06, runif(100), simplify = FALSE)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    847.1    13.9

rm(x)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     23.2     9.4
```

##### `tcmalloc`

```bash
$ sudo apt install libtcmalloc-minimal4
$ env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 R --vanilla
```

```r
usage <- function() {
    m1 <- sum(gc(FALSE)[, "(Mb)"])
    m2 <- as.double(system(paste("ps -p", Sys.getpid(), "-o pmem="), intern = TRUE))
    c(`gc (MiB)` = m1, `ps (%)` = m2)
}
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     19.0     0.7

x <- replicate(1e+06, runif(100), simplify = FALSE)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    847.1    13.8

rm(x)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     23.2    13.8
```

##### `malloc`+`malloc_trim`, via Simon Urbanek's `mallinfo::malloc.trim`

```bash
$ R --vanilla
```

```r
usage <- function() {
    m1 <- sum(gc(FALSE)[, "(Mb)"])
    m2 <- as.double(system(paste("ps -p", Sys.getpid(), "-o pmem="), intern = TRUE))
    c(`gc (MiB)` = m1, `ps (%)` = m2)
}
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     19.0     0.7

x <- replicate(1e+06, runif(100), simplify = FALSE)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##    847.1    15.9

rm(x)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     23.2    15.8

## install.packages("mallinfo", repos = "http://www.rforge.net/")
mallinfo::malloc.trim(0L)
usage()
## gc (MiB)  ps (%) 
##     23.2     0.6
```